# Why is the ground state of an atom never degenerate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, eigenvalue, ground-state

In this paper https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01391720 , Kellner argues that the ground state of the helium atom must be spherically symmetric because "it is known that the ground state eigenvalue is simple, and therefore only a single ground state wave function exists" - no reference w.r.t the 'it is known' part, and I can't figure out why.

So - why is the ground state energy a simple eigenvalue? Is it because the Hamiltonian is hermitian, somehow?

Answer (score 2):

> So - why is the ground state energy a simple eigenvalue? Is it because the Hamiltonian is Hermitian, somehow?

No. The statement isn't true in general: there are quantum mechanical systems with degenerate ground states. Anytime there is an operator $\hat U$ that commutes with the Hamiltonian and acts non-trivially on a ground state, the ground state will be degenerate, since $\hat U\left|\psi_0\right\rangle$ then describes a distinct ground state.

Indeed, is isn't even true for all atoms. For instance, the paper [Quantum chemical calculations show that the uranium molecule U$_2$ has a quintuple bond](https://doi.org/10.1038/nature03249) states that the uranium atom's ground state is 17-fold degenerate:

> The ground state of the uranium atom is $^{5}$L, which is 17-fold degenerate.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Is there a way of arguing that it is true for two-electron atoms (with fixed nucleus)?

Comment: @Giogina [This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/405526/106502) gets part of the way there. You can treat the electrons as separate aside from requiring anti-symmetrization and treat the electron-electron interaction as a perturbation. Since both electrons fit into the 1s state all that really remains is convincing yourself that the electron-electron perturbation can't possibly be a larger difference than the jump in energy from 1s to 2s.